# assigning void pointer to another void pointer

Tags: c++, void

Is it safe to assign void pointer to another void pointer such that both pointers will point to same thing, and then operate on one of them.

for example I'm trying to do something like this: (just an example)
`HANDLE` is typedefed as `void*`

```
HANDLE hPrevious = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(...);

hPrevious = hFile; // assigning

CloseHandle(hPrevious); // now both handles are invalid?

hPrevious = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE; // now both handles are INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE

// hFile is released
```

Is assigning one void* to another and then operating on one of them same as operating on both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CloseHandle(hPrevious); // now both handles are invalid?
```

Yep, they're both closed now.

```
hPrevious = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE; // now both handles are INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
```

This only modifies `hPrevious`. `hFile` is not changed. Pointers don't have any spooky action-at-a-distance until they're dereferenced with `*`.